# Importing file into SAS using data step

Tags: sas

I'm trying to import a sas dataset into SAS, using a data step. It is tab-delimited. Here is my code so far. When I go to run the data, it runs but then the output data looks all wrong. Is there a better way to do this?

```
data medicare;
    infile '/folders/myfolders/sasuser.v94/medicare.sas' dlm='09'X;
    input NPI NPPES_CREDENTIALS $ NPPES_PROVIDER_GENDER $ NPPES_ENTITY_CODE $ NPPES_PROVIDER_ZIP $ NPPES_PROVIDER_STATE $ PROVIDER_TYPE $ MEDICARE_PARTICIPATION_INDICATOR $ PLACE_OF_SERVICE $ HCPCS_CODE $ HCPCS_DRUG_INDICATOR $ LINE_SRVC_CNT BENE_UNIQUE_CNT BENE_DAY_SRVC_CNT AVERAGE_MEDICARE_ALLOWED_AMT STDEV_MEDICARE_ALLOWED_AMT AVERAGE_SUBMITTED_CHRG_AMT STDEV_SUBMITTED_CHRG_AMT AVERAGE_MEDICARE_PAYMENT_AMT sSTDEV_MEDICARE_PAYMENT_AMT;
run;
```

Comment: A .sas file is a program, it's a text file but it would be very unusual for that to hold data only. That extension is usually used for SAS programs. A SAS dataset has an extension of sas7bdat.

Comment: Please post a sample of the data you're trying to import. Feel free to replace any sensitive info with dummy values.

Comment: You must initialize your variables with `length` statements. If you don't and some fields in your tab-delimited file are longer than 8 characters, they will be truncated. Also, you may need to use the `dsd` and/or `missover` options on your `infile` statement depending on your file's contents.

Comment: "Looks all wrong" is not very helpful for troubleshooting issues.  Please explain what is wrong with your dataset.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a beginner-friendly approach, you can first run proc import. SAS will guess the correct data types, lengths, etc. Here is an example:

```
filename imp "C:\Users\&sysuserid.\Documents\xxx.txt" encoding="cp1252" TERMSTR=CRLF;

proc import datafile=imp
out=imported_table
dbms=dlm 
replace;
delimiter='09'x;
getnames=yes;
guessingrows = 1000000;
run;
```

Then, copy the data step code SAS prints into the log and update it (if needed).